# Can't pass color to FragmentShader

Tags: c, opengl, glsl, shader

I'm trying to pass the color of my triangle through my main function, but when I try to do it my triangle only gets white like it has no fragment shader

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;

out vec3 color;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position
    color = aColor;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 color;
out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
 FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
};
```

main code:

```
 float positions[] = {
      -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.f, 0.8f, 0.3f, 0.02f,                       //inferior esquerdo
      0.5, -0.5f, 0.f, 0.8f, 0.3f, 0.2f,                          //inferior direito
      0.0f, (sqrt(3.f) - 1.f) / 2.f, 0.f, 1.f, 0.6f, 0.32f,       //Topo
      -0.5f / 2.f, (0.37f - 0.5f) / 2.f, 0.f, 0.9f, 0.45f, 0.17f, //Meio esquerdo
      0.5f / 2, (0.37f - 0.5f) / 2.f, 0.f, 0.9f, 0.45f, 0.17f,    //Meio direito
      0.f, -0.5f, 0.f, 0.8f, 0.3f, 0.02f};                        //Meio
 unsigned int indices[9] =
      {
          0, 5, 3,
          5, 1, 4,
          3, 4, 2};

  unsigned int buffer, attribute, EBO;
  //Gera o Shader
  struct Shader shaderProgram = beginShader("res/shaders/sv1.shader", "res/shaders/sf1.shader");
  //Gerao Vertex Array Object e bainda ele
  struct VAO vao1 = beginVAO();
  vao1.Bind(vao1);

  //Gera o Vertex Buffer linkando-o ao vértice
  struct VBO vbo1 = beginVBO(positions, sizeof(positions));
  //Gera o Element Buffer e linka ele com os índices do vetor posições
  struct EBO ebo1 = beginEBO(indices, sizeof(indices));

  //Conecta o VBO ao VAO
  vao1.LinkAttrib(vbo1, 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, 6 * sizeof(float), (void *)0);
  vao1.LinkAttrib(vbo1, 1, 3, GL_FLOAT, 6 * sizeof(float), (void *)(3 * sizeof(float)));
  //Unbind em todos os objetos que foram bindados
  vao1.Unbind(vao1);
  vbo1.Unbind(vbo1);
  ebo1.Unbind(ebo1);

  while (true)
  {
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&windowEvent))
    {
      if (SDL_QUIT == windowEvent.type)
      {
        break;
      }
    }
    glClearColor(0.05f, 0.57f, 0.38f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    shaderProgram.Activate(shaderProgram);
    vao1.Bind(vao1);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 9, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glEnd();
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window); //update the window
  }
  vao1.Delete(vao1);
  vbo1.Delete(vbo1);
  ebo1.Delete(ebo1);
  shaderProgram.Delete(shaderProgram);
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_Quit();
```

LinkAttrib function:

```
void LinkAttrib(struct VBO VBO, GLuint layout, GLuint numComponents, GLenum type, 
GLsizeiptr stride, void *offset)
{
 VBO.Bind(VBO);
 glVertexAttribPointer(layout, numComponents, type, GL_FALSE, stride, offset);
 glEnableVertexAttribArray(layout);
 VBO.Unbind(VBO);
}
```

As I'm written in C the functions I create have to pass the own struct as param si I have the functions begin to attribute to each function trying to simulate an object. The function begin shader gets the file with the shaders and compile them and generate the Program Shader, the begin VAO generate the vertex array object
This the draw I have
[image]

Comment: I forgot the shader, sorry

Comment: I put it, but still not working, but it is a begining

Comment: there is a spurious `;` after  the `main` function body in the fragment shader.

Comment: Are you sure that the shader files are being read correctly?

Comment: Why is there a `glEnd` in your code?

Comment: glEnd is in the while loop. I tried to add some debug when compiling the shaders and I'm getting the following: `Failed to compile fragment shader

Fragment shader failed to compile with the following errors:
ERROR: 0:9: error(#132) Syntax error: "<" parse error
ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors.  No code generated`

Comment: Have you removed the `;` at the end?

Comment: I removed it. I was doing some tests I get one right result. I'm starting to think that the problem is in the functions that read the shaders wich is adding a random character when it needs to read the second shader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vertex shader doesn't compile for 2 reasons:

1. There is missing a `;` after `gl_Position = position`
2. `gl_Position` and `position` have different types

<s>`gl_Position = position`</s>

```c
gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
```

Comment: @EduardoMosca The shader is fine now. There is no further error in the shader code.